# mysql database edited in phpmyadmin does not return query in php script

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, phpmyadmin

This is a weird problem. I have a field called status in a database table called Parents. Via a php script, I entered a bunch of parents with status of 'active'. Later, I used phpmyadmin to change two of them to a status of 'dormant'. When I run a query asking for rows with status of active, all is well in both phpmyadmin and in my php script. When I run a query asking for rows with status of dormant, phpmyadmin returns the two rows whose status is dormant, but my php script does not return any rows. Here are the relevant pieces of the code:

```
// get value of radio button for $active
$active = stripslashes(strip_tags($_POST['active']));
if (!$active) {
  $active = 'active';
}

// Similar process for value of $myOrderby, 
// which can have value of 'name' or 'email' and works fine

$query = "SELECT 
    Parents.parentID, 
    Parents.parentName, 
    Parents.parentEmail, 
    Students.nickName,
    Students.Lname
  FROM Parents, Students
  WHERE Parents.parentID=Students.parentID
    AND Parents.status=:active
  ORDER BY $myOrderby ASC" ;
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindValue(':active', $active, PDO::PARAM_STR);

try {
   $stmt->execute();
   $affected_rows = $stmt->rowCount();
   if ($affected_rows > 0) {
      // various actions...
   }
} catch (PDOException $ex) {
   $message = $ex->getMessage() ;
   $filename = 'admin-parents' ;
   notifyMe($message, $filename) ;
}
```

Curiously, however, if I again use phpmyadmin to change the two rows whose status is 'dormant' back to a status of 'active' (not using any punctuation in the input box) those two rows do NOT show up in the php results for all active parents. That is the problem that started me on this entire quest.

CLARIFICATION: myphpadmin query ALWAYS returns correct result for these two rows, both when status is 'active' and when status is 'dormant'. (I change them via myphpadmin.) However, php script NEVER returns these two rows, regardless of their status.

Comment: are you doing **$stmt->execute();**?

Comment: What do you see if you `SELECT DISTINCT status FROM Parents` - basically, is there an issue with the status that those rows have been assigned?

Comment: Your "default value" always gets stomped by the subsequent assignment. Why are you doing that? Also `stripslashes` is to undo the damage caused by the "magic quotes" feature that shouldn't be on in the first place and `strip_tags` is totally useless.

Comment: SQL.injection - yes, see code added above.
tadman - First time page loads, there is no value of $active because form (to resort list) has not been submitted. Actually doing something a little different; see revision above On other comments, thanks. Re-using some old code, clearly.

andrewsi - assuming you mean in phpmyadmin, I get two rows: first is active, second is dormant.

Comment: @andrewsi - It returns two rows: one says active and the other dormant. What does this tell us towards solving the problem? (PS I will be out of office until Monday; not ignoring anyone.)

Comment: @wynSnow It's telling you that you've still got records in the database with a status of dormant; so it looks like when you updated the records back to status, it didn't work. That at least explains when they're not showing up when you now search for active records.

Comment: @andrewsi - Clarification: myphpadmin query ALWAYS returns correct result for these two rows, both when status is 'active' and when status is 'dormant'. (I change them via myphpadmin.) However, php script NEVER returns these two rows, regardless of their status.

Comment: @WynSnow - this is a silly question, but are you sure that your PHP script is pointing at the same database as PhpMyAdmin? Otherwise, I'd modify your query for debugging - leave the JOIN in, and select the two errant records by ID, and output all the columns to see if there's anything unexpected in there.

Comment: @andrewsi - All silly questions welcome! (Is it plugged in?) Yes, I'm sure it is same database. When php query asks for status='active', php script returns all the active Parent rows - except for these two that I edited via phpmyadmin. But yes, that's a good suggestion to select the errant records by ID and see if the php script returns them. Will report on this either Monday or Tues.

Comment: @andrewsi - aha! Yes, it will return those rows by ID number. It will also return those rows if I remove the join to Students and specify :active as 'dormant'. Turns out, those two Parent rows have no Students enrolled, so my query only returns rows where the Parent has a Student enrolled. Not exactly what I wanted/anticipated! :-( But thanks! Your question got me on the route to figuring out what was happening!!

Comment: @WynSnow - no problem at all; I'm glad you managed to figure out what happened!

Comment: @andrewsi - Me too! I got it working the way I want = YAY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out: The two rows in Parent table with status of 'dormant' did NOT have any rows in the Student table. The query returns only rows where a Parent also has a Student. Which is not exactly what I intended. Back to the drawing board! But I am SO relieved to understand the source of the problem! Thanks everyone! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set which button was selected by the user, use result as parameter in query
Assuming radio buttons set up as

```
<Input type = 'radio' Name ='active' value= 'active'>Active
<Input type = 'radio' Name ='active' value= 'dormant'>Dormant


// get value of radio button for $active
$active = $_POST['active'];

}
ETC..............
```

Assign parameters

```
$stmt->bindValue(':active', $active, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Comment: And how do I use that in the mysql query? (PS will be out of office until Monday -- not ignoring anyone.)

Comment: I don't understand how to use this information or how it is relevant to the query.

Comment: intriguing. How does the value of $status differ from value of $selected_radio?

Comment: It doesn't. Need more coffee.

Comment: okay, that's reassuring, since what you suggest is exactly what I did, except I also added a default value for $active. Thanks, and good luck on the coffee! <grin>